# RegEx Starts with [ and ending with ]

Tags: c#, regex

What is the Regular Expression to find the strings starting with [ and ending with ]. Between [ and] all kind of character are fine.

Comment: Are you trying to find these strings inside a larger body of text? If so, can brackets be nested?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to  find the strings in a larger body. But I am not  expecting nested brackets.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`[` and `]` are special characters in regular expressions, so you need to escape them. This should work for you:

```
\[.*?\]
```

`.*?` does non-greedy matching of any character. The non-greedy aspect assures that you will match `[abc]` instead of `[abc]def]`. Add a leading `^` and trailing `$` if you want to match the entire string, e.g. no match at all in `abc[def]ghi`.

Comment: This does not match start and end, this means: Contains

Answer (score 14):

```
^\[.*\]$
```

will match a string that starts with `[` and ends with `]`. In C#:

```
foundMatch = Regex.IsMatch(subjectString, @"^\[.*\]$");
```

If you're looking for bracket-delimited strings inside longer strings (e. g. find `[bar]` within `foo [bar] baz`), then use

```
\[[^[\]]*\]
```

In C#:

```
MatchCollection allMatchResults = null;
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"\[[^[\]]*\]");
allMatchResults = regexObj.Matches(subjectString);
```

**Explanation:**

```
\[        # match a literal [
 [^[\]]*  # match zero or more characters except [ or ]
\]        # match a literal ]
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether yours or thecoop's answer is the best, but I assume yours because the OP never mentioned that there should be ANY characters between the [ and ], and therefore your `*` is a better match than thecoop's `+`.

Answer (score 7):

This should work:

```
^\[.+\]$
```

`^` is 'start of string'
`\[` is an escaped [, because [ is a control character
`.+` matches all strings of length >= 1 (`.` is 'any character', `+` means 'match previous pattern one or more times')
`\]` is an escaped ]
`$` is 'end of string'

If you want to match `[]` as well, change the `+` to a `*` ('match zero or more times')

Then use the `Regex` class to match:

```
bool match = Regex.IsMatch(input, "^\[.+\]$");
```

or, if you're using this several times or in a loop, create a `Regex` instance for better performance:

```
private static readonly Regex s_MyRegexPatternThingy = new Regex("^\[.+\]$");

bool match = s_MyRegexPatternThingy.IsMatch(input);
```

Comment: The worked expression is \[.*?\], however your description is helpful too

Answer (score 2):

You need to use escape character `\` for brackets.
Use `.+` if you like to have at least 1 character between the brackets or `.*` if you accept this string: `[]`.

```
^\[.*\]$
```